# How to create an array from string seperated values?

Tags: php

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mechanical Engineering,CEO
)
```

Now I want to convert it in this form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mechanical Engineering
    [1] => CEO
)
```

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/explode) is your friend.

Comment: may be explode is not his friend ! You should introduce to him :)

Comment: Does your input contain only one key 0? Or can it contain multiple keys? Also, will it make any difference to the output?

Comment: explode did the work....thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like below.

```
$str = 'Mechanical Engineering,CEO';
$arrayStr = explode(',',$str );
print_r($arrayStr);
```

Comment: but what if at first I have                                                                     $str = 'Mechanical Engineering';     ain't in this case explode will give error.

Comment: we have to store  [0] => Mechanical Engineering,CEO in $str variable or you can also pass direct array value like your array is $x = array('Mechanical Engineering,CEO') then we can use

$arrayStr = explode(',', $x[0]);
print_r($arrayStr);

hope it will clear now

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Assuming your input array has only one key "Mechanical Engineering,CEO".

We need [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function to access the array element.

Since you want to split your data every time there's a comma, we need [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
 function.

```
$input  = array("Mechanical Engineering,CEO");
$output = explode(",", current($input));
```